# Grouping routes in Silex

Tags: symfony, silex, bolt-cms

Inside a Bolt extension, I've got lots of routes bound to an instance of the App, like this:

```
$this->app->post(Extension::API_PREFIX . "session", array($this, 'login'))
              ->bind('login');
$this->app->delete(Extension::API_PREFIX . "session", array($this, 'logout'))
              ->bind('logout');


$this->app->post(Extension::API_PREFIX . "resetpassword", array($this, 'reset_password'))
              ->bind('reset_password');

$this->app->post(Extension::API_PREFIX . "forgotpassword", array($this, 'forgot_password'))
              ->bind('forgot_password');

$this->app->post(Extension::API_PREFIX . "changepassword", array($this, 'change_password'))
              ->bind('change_password');

$this->app->get(Extension::API_PREFIX . "session", array($this, 'get_session'))
              ->bind('get_session');
```

But I want to run a `before` filter on a subset of the routes. How can I group some of these routes together and bind the filter? So far, I've only found out how I could have the filter on *all* the routes, like this:

```
$this->app->before(function (Request $request) {    
    // Filter request here
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

The [ControllerCollection class forwards its calls to each of the controllers it holds](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/1.2/src/Silex/ControllerCollection.php#L155). So you could do something like (untested code!):

```
<?php
// intializations, etc.

// this will give you a new ControllerCollection class
$collection = $this->app['controllers_factory'];

$collection->post(Extension::API_PREFIX . "session", array($this, 'login'))
           ->bind('login');
// etc.

// Apply middleware:
$collection->before(function(Request $request) {
  // do whatever you want in your filter
});

// Mount the collection to a certain URL:
$this->app->mount('/mount-point', $collection);  // if you don't want /mount-point 
                                                 // just pass an empty string
```

Note that this will only work if you put all the routes under the same PATH as you need to "mount" the collection in order to enable the routes (you already do with `Extension::API_PREFIX`)